# How can I prevent edited commands from overwriting the original? Or revert edits?

Tags: bash, command-history

Often I'll execute a command in bash, press the up arrow to retrieve it from history, edit it, and execute the edit.  However, sometimes I'll decide to discard the edit and run a different command or something.  This poses a problem because the edited command, which I didn't run, gets saved over top of the original history entry so I can no longer run the original with ease.

For example, here's the end of my current history:

```
2132* svn cleanup && svn up --set-de
2133  history
```

The first command was originally `svn cleanup && svn up --set-depth=infinity folder1 folder2`.

Is there a way to disable overwrites or revert them to the original commands?

Comment: Zsh behaves the way you want.

Answer (score 2):

Abort the line editing with ctrl+c instead of deleting the command, that way bash doesn't overwrite the history line.

Comment: This works, thanks for the quick response!  I usually press up or down to move to another history entry however, rather than backspacing the line clear -- if I'm more than a couple lines up into the history I'll also be annoyed/slowed by Ctrl+C losing my place and needing to tap up again.